# Watching video in chrome is very laggy

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I am using Debian 11 and when I tried to play a video in chrome it is very laggy.
I am dual booting Debian and windows But in windows, there is no issue. Anyone, please help me regarding the issue. (Chrome is up to date).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can upgrade your hardware to handle the video or your internet connection is unstable, leading to the laggy playback.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1120739)